# Extension of Apache parquet files, is it '.pqt' or '.parquet'?

Tags: file, format

I wonder if there is a consensus regarding the extension of parquet files. I have seen a shorter `.pqt` extension, which has typical 3-letters (like in csv, tsv, txt, etc) and then there is a rather long (therefore unconventional(?)) `.parquet` extension which is widely used.

Anybody knows what extension is "official", and if the use of `.pqt` (which I personally like) would be ok.

Answer (score 24):

`.parquet` is the most commonly used extension. Three letter file extensions are a remnant of the days when file lengths were very restricted. It's quite common to see longer names nowadays (e.g. database.sqlite).